# Could not Run the App after updating kotlin plugin to 1.2.51

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After Updating my Kotlin Plugin to 1.2.51 this error about annotation processor pop up, This happens every time I build the app, whether I try to run it in Emulator or real device, 
I tried to add annotationprocessor Configuration as mentioned in Error Log in a build file, then again another error pops up :

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'kotlin/reflect/reflect.kotlin_builtins'
```

Mind this, It happens only When I try to build It doesn't show up when I try to sync Gradle, I have tried Invalidate Cache and Restart too but no help

**Error Pic 1:**

[image: Error Pic 1]

**Error Pic 2:**

[image: Error Pic 2]

Comment: You added kotlin gradle plugin in app dependencies section. It seems that you put it in the wrong place and must be in buildscript section. Please post your app and root gradle files.

Comment: [root gradle](https://i.imgur.com/wz0mzVi.png)

Comment: Any reason for using kotlin gradle plugin in app dependencies section?

Comment: **Update**: After removing kotlin Gradle plugin from app dependency it Solved the error, But I would like to know why does this happen in the first place, It was by default present in there when I build project but after android studio kotlin plugin update, it showed up.